# Allow users to change theme but not desktop Windows Server 2012

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, desktop

I am running Windows Server 2012 for a school. I have recently updated the computers to Windows 10.

I am trying to allow students to change their theme, but not their desktop background. In GP, I had it set to allow students to change their theme, but allowing them to change their desktop image was disabled.

I logged in as a test student and was able to change the theme, but the desktop image does not change and there is a message at the bottom of the settings screen saying that one or more of the options have been disabled by the administrator.

If I enable the setting allowing students to change their desktop background, changing the theme changes the background image.

I want to do this so they will be able to customize their computer, but I don't want to allow them to change to any image they download off the internet.

Another note, I have disabled users from changing their lock screen image, but the option is still available. Is this setting not available in Windows 10 yet?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Windows 10 Administrative template added to your server.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48257

I have also found a lot of the Windows 10 configurations can be added using Windows 10 RSAT tools on a Windows 10 computer without even adding the Windows 10 Administrative tools. They will appear on the server GP side as registry keys I believe.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: I was able to use the registry key "DisableLogonBackgroundImage" to disable the windows logo on all machines using group policy. I tried using "NoDispBackgroundPage". This worked in Windows XP, but doesn't seem to do anything in windows 10 and I don't see any settings like that in the new administrative template. Any further ideas?